Lightning Modal not getting focus when opened
I have created a component(modalParent) having lightning modal(myModal) using SLDS.
When the modal is opened, ideally it should get auto focus but that is not happening.
The focus is on the background interactive items.
I want the focus to move to modal.
I have tried setting focus to heading inside modal using javascript focus in renderedCallback but that is also not working as nothing gets displayed when renderedCallback is called.
modalParent.html
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_stacked">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label">"Parent Modal"</label>

        <!-- Modal Component -->
        <template if:true={isModalOpen}>
            <c-my-modal onclose={handleModalClose} content={_value} class="parentFromModal"></c-my-modal>
        </template>

        <div class="slds-form-element__control odc-rich-text" disabled={disabled} title="edit">
            <!-- Editable when not disabled -->
            <template if:false={disabled}>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                   class="slds-box odc-rich-text-action rich-text-container"
                   onclick={openModal}
                   aria-label={_ariaLabel}
                   role = "button"
                   title="Edit Rich Text Content">
                    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={_value}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                </a>
            </template>
            <!-- Non-clickable view when disabled -->
            <template if:true={disabled}>
                <div class="slds-box odc-rich-text-action">
                    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={_value}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

modalParent.js
import { api, track, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ModalParent extends LightningElement {
    @api disabled;
    @api label;
    @api fieldLevelHelp;
    _value;
    @track isModalOpen = false;
    @api get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
    set value(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    disabled = false;
    label = "Instructions Label"

    renderedCallback() {
    }

    openModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
    }

    handleModalClose(event) {
        const newValue = event.detail;
        if (newValue !== null && newValue !== undefined && newValue !== this._value) {
            this._value = newValue;
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change'));
        }
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }
}

myModal.html
<template>
    <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open odc_modal" role="dialog" aria-label="I am aria label" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" onkeydown={handleKeyDown} tabindex="0">
      <div class="slds-modal__container" tabindex="-1">
              <header class="slds-modal__header">
                  <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">My Modal</h2>
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={handleCancel}>
                      <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="Close" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                  </button>
              </header>
  
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <lightning-button onclick={handleOptionClick}>
                  ButtonLabel
              </lightning-button>
            </div>
  
              <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                  <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
                  <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
              </footer>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
    </div>
  </template>

myModal.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MyModal extends LightningElement {
    @api content = '';

    handleKeyDown(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        const cardElement = this.template.querySelector('.odc_modal');
        console.log("Printing the data");
        console.log(event.key);
        console.log(cardElement);
        console.log("Now printing event target");
        console.log(event.target);
        if (event.target === cardElement && event.key === 'Escape') {
            this.handleCancel();
        }
    }

    handleSave() {
        const tinyMceEditor = this.template.querySelector('builder_omnistudio_common-rich-text-editor');
        const content = tinyMceEditor.getContent();
        const saveEvent = new CustomEvent('close', {
            detail : content
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(saveEvent);
    }

    handleCancel() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('close'));
    }
}


Seems like the modalParent.html form classes are the reason. Putting modal inside lighting-card, seems to resolve the issue.
